# jQuery show/hide each element in list

Tags: javascript, jquery

The problem is that I want to change innerHTML propery of  for each name in list and animate it with (fadeIn,delay for x sec,fadeOut)

```
<div id="welcomeBox">Welcome SOMETHING</div>

var list = ["George","Bob","Tom"];

$.each(list, function()
{
    $("#welcomeBox")
        .eq(0)
        .text('Welcome' + this)
        .fadeToggle(1500)
        .delay(5000)
        .fadeToggle(1500);
});
```

With code above I just get 3x Welcome Tom message.

Comment: id's should be unique, so `.eq(0)` shouldn't bee needed.

Comment: thx on comment, but that's not the answer on the question up there

Comment: i didn't realize the comment section was for posting answers. my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var list=["George","Bob","Tom"];

// recursive closure to iterate thru list
(function recurse(index){
    // on fade use the callback to fade out
    $("#welcomeBox").text('Welcome ' + list[index]).fadeIn(1500, function(){
        $("#welcomeBox").fadeOut(1500, function(){
            // after fade out, call the function again with the next index
            recurse(undefined !== list[index+1] ? index+1 : 0);
        });
    });
})(0);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6qo0L6mr/